# Position reset when minimizing

Tags: c#, monogame

When I start my application, the object spawns at the given position (given vector). But when I minimize the monogame window and reopen it, then the object is in the upper-left corner.

Why is this happening?

NOTE: this is my `Draw` method:

```
public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    // Position is the object position 
    spriteBatch.Draw(textureImage, position, new Rectangle(
    (currentFrame.X * frameSize.X),
    (currentFrame.Y * frameSize.Y),
    frameSize.X, frameSize.Y),
    Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero, 2, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
}
```

How the starting position is calculated:

```
// Vector2 position is the starting position for the object

public PlayerMovement(Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position, Point frameSize, int collisionOffSet, Point currentFrame, Point startFrame, Point sheetSize, float speed, float speedMultiplier, float millisecondsPerFrame)
        : base(textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffSet, currentFrame, startFrame, sheetSize, speed, speedMultiplier, millisecondsPerFrame)
{
        children = new List<Sprite>();
}
```

I use `Vector2 direction` to know which direction the sprite is facing:

```
public abstract Vector2 direction
    {
        get;
    }
```

I use the `get` in my `PlayerMovement` class and return `inputDirection * speed`

(`inputDirection` is a `Vector2`)

Finally in my `Update` method, I do `position += direction` and I also check if the player isn't touching the borders of the screen(he can't move out the screen.).

Comment: how are currentFrame and frameSize calculated?

Comment: `currentFrame` is the current frame in the animation. I assigned a variable for how long the game waits when it displays the next sprite in the animation. The `frameSize` is how big one sprite in an animation is (how many pixels in height and in witdth). But this is not the problem I think, because the animations work well.

Comment: Do I check for `IsActive` in the main `Game` class?

Comment: Yes, `IsActive` belongs to `Game`, but I was thinking of another fix I made (so comment deleted). I checked my change history for that project and what happened is that the way I was setting position was doing a ` < 0` check, and minimizing the game was creating VERY invalid values so that the check I was doing basically reset everything to zero (to keep things in bounds). Can we see how position is calculated?

Comment: I updated my information on the position.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using `Game.Window.ClientBounds` to keep player from moving out of the screen?

Comment: yes, so that the player can't walk outside of the screen

Comment: Ok - I'll update with an answer later today (I have meetings :-/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience, using `Game.Window.ClientBounds` in an `Update` call has caused problems when the window is minimized. Here is some sample code from my project:

```
Rectangle gdm = Game.Window.ClientBounds;
if (DrawLocation.X < 0) DrawLocation = new Vector2(0, DrawLocation.Y);
if (DrawLocation.Y < 0) DrawLocation = new Vector2(DrawLocation.X, 0);
if (DrawLocation.X > gdm.Width - DrawAreaWithOffset.Width) DrawLocation = new Vector2(gdm.Width - DrawAreaWithOffset.Width, DrawLocation.Y);
if (DrawLocation.Y > gdm.Height - DrawAreaWithOffset.Height) DrawLocation = new Vector2(DrawLocation.X, gdm.Height - DrawAreaWithOffset.Height);
```

The problem I had when minimizing was that Game.Window.ClientBounds was returning some width/height around `-32000`. This would always reset my game objects to some default location when restoring the window. I fixed it by first checking that the ClientBounds `Width` and `Height` were both greater than zero:

```
Rectangle gdm = Game.Window.ClientBounds;
if (gdm.Width > 0 && gdm.Height > 0) //protect when window is minimized
{
    if (DrawLocation.X < 0)
        DrawLocation = new Vector2(0, DrawLocation.Y);
    if (DrawLocation.Y < 0)
        DrawLocation = new Vector2(DrawLocation.X, 0);
    if (DrawLocation.X > gdm.Width - DrawAreaWithOffset.Width)
        DrawLocation = new Vector2(gdm.Width - DrawAreaWithOffset.Width, DrawLocation.Y);
    if (DrawLocation.Y > gdm.Height - DrawAreaWithOffset.Height)
        DrawLocation = new Vector2(DrawLocation.X, gdm.Height - DrawAreaWithOffset.Height);
}
```

For reference, here is a [diff of changes](https://github.com/ethanmoffat/XNAControls/commit/2ca34333adfc6f802d9e7b16e0a851d5790e16a3) that fixed the minimize problem for my own project.

A separate bug I was having involved interaction with the game still happening when the game was not the primary, active window. You can also add a check for `Game.IsActive` at the beginning of your `Update` and `Draw` calls:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gt)
{
    if(!IsActive) return;
    //etc...
}
```

Or if using Game Components, your component update/draw would look like:

```
public override void Update(GameTime gt)
{
    if(!Game.IsActive) return;
    //etc...
}
```